# Establish VPN connection using React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, vpn

Is it possible to create a VPN app like NordVPN or CyberGhost VPN using React Native?

My main question is how to establish connection to VPN using React Native? Is there any component to do that?

Comment: why don't you check out vpn apps like shadowrocket?